# Como mostrar los valores de una clase sin crear otra instancia de la clase

Tags: java, class, constructor

Como mostrar los valores de una clase sin crear otra instancia de la clase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: and please read this link: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Por favor, el código se adjunta en texto, no se coloca en una imagen.

Answer (score 1):

En el ejemplo que nos muestras en la imagen, el objeto esta definido en el case 1, lo que hace imposible que lo puedas llamar en el case 2 ya que para cada case del switch, si definimos variables dentro de este, las tomara privadas y solo se podrán utilizar en el case que están definidas.

Si la opción es utilizar globalmente este objeto, te recomiendo definir las variables antes de los métodos.

Si la opción es utilizar la variable solo en un método te recomiendo:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Persona p = null;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese un valor");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        switch (a) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Nombre:");
                String b = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Apellido:");
                String c = sc.nextLine();
                p = new Persona(b, c);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Nombre " + p.getX());
                break;
        }
    }
```